# check if a div is hidden or not while using a toggle

Tags: jquery

i am using a toggle function such that when i click on a button a div shows up and when i again click that button it hides . but the problem is i also have one more close button in the div that closes the div, it means when i clicked the button the toggle was incomplete and when i try to open the div again through that toggle button then first it completes the toggle means again hide the already hidden div and then again show it , any solution for that ?

```
$(".stngs").toggle(function() {
    $(".stngsubmenu").css({
        display: 'block'
    });
}, function() {    
    $(".stngsubmenu").css({
        display: 'none'
    });
});​
```

Comment: have you tried `.is(":hidden")` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ you can just pass a boolean into the toggle

```
$(".stngs").toggle($(".stngsubmenu").is(':visible'));
```

or

```
$(".stngs").toggle($(".stngsubmenu").is(':hidden'));
```

true will show element and false will hide which the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function will return a boolean

`$(".stngsubmenu").is(':visible')` // <-- will return true if visible

`$(".stngsubmenu").is(':hidden')` // <-- will return true if hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/KXPBq/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to check if something is hidden

```
if ( $('#mydiv').is(':hidden') ) {
    //do something
}
```